# How can I unblock cdn-cf.fabric.io?

Tags: android, crashlytics, fabric.io

I don't know why but I am occasionally seeing this error after being logged for a while.

> We couldn't load assets!
>   Please make sure cdn-cf.fabric.io is not
>   blocked and try again.

[image]

The only way to get out this screen is by cleaning up my cache. How can I unblock this host?

**More details:**

- Operational System: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6
- Chrome version: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

It happens to me straight after cleaning up my browser data, login and refresh the browser.

**List of extensions**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Do you have any extensions or plugins installed that could be looking some of our requests?

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell. Actually no. I don't make use of such plugins

Comment: Gotcha, that's the only time I've seen this happen before other then when one of our services was down and thus couldn't be loaded, but that's very rare. How often are you hitting it?

Comment: It's happening right now but just from the Macbook + Chrome. I am accessing from Brazil. I added some more details that might be useful.

Comment: Can you share a list of all extensions or plugins you have installed?

Comment: Sure. See my update. Mike, thanks for helping me out. The problem seems to be "solved" now after restoring Chrome settings to original defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem "seems" to be solved after restoring Chrome settings to original defaults

[image]

Comment: Hmm, strange, but glad you're all set!

Comment: @MikeBonnell I've experienced the same, tried to narrow down the issue, but failed and had to restore defaults.

Comment: Thanks @WladekSurala I still haven't been to reproduce this, but glad Victor's answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i'm accessing from China. After i change my VPN setting to `global schema` the page works.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend:

- Clear browser cached data
- Refresh fabric.io and it will work property.

[image: clear browser cached data]